# How to Read xml without knowing its structure

Tags: xml

Whether we can read an XML file without knowing strucutre. Can we also perform some kind of mapping between nodes.For example my XML will be

```
<bookstore>
  <location category="US">
  <book category="cooking">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>XYZ</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
  <book category="sample">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <writer>ABCD</writer>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
 </location>

    <location category="UK">
  <book category="cooking">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
  <book category="sample">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <writer>Giada De Laurentiis</writer>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
 </location>
</bookstore>
```

In this sample XMl, i want to read the bookstore in location US and its authors.Here authors and writers are simillar so I want to consider writer as also a author.I want to extract author names.(i.e) output will be XYZ,ABC. How can i perform this mapping.How can i read this without knowing the structure.Is there anyway to do this.Is it possible? first.Sorry if its a dumb question.

Comment: You have the file, so you already know its structure.  XML is by definition structured, and any program that processes it must expect _some_ structure.  Your question is not clear.

Comment: Did you read it fully.I need to perform mapping too.Not only on single xml file.But multiple Xml files.

Comment: So you'll have to abstract some common structure from all the possible inputs. You have to have _something_ on which to base your decisions, and without seeing several different inputs we can't help you get started.  If there is absolutely no commonality, either in nesting structure or tag names, then no, you cannot write code that will successfully handle it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a dumb question per-se, but it's hard to answer without more detail. XML is a structured data format.

However parsers - like `perl`s `XML::Twig` - can do things like traverse up and down nodes, and parse the structure dynamically. So you could - for example - merge `author` and `writer`.

E.g. YOu could do something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my %books;

sub process_book {
    my ( $twig, $book ) = @_;
    $book->print;
    print "--\n";
    my $title = $book->first_child('title')->text;
    if ( $books{$title} ) {
        foreach my $element ( $book->children ) {
            if ( not $books{$title}->first_child( $element->tag ) ) {
                my $new_element = $element->cut;
                $new_element->paste( $books{$title} );
            }
        }
        $book->delete;
    }
    else {
        $books{$title} = $book;
    }
}

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    pretty_print  => 'indented',
    twig_handlers => { 'book' => \&process_book, },
)->parse( \*DATA );
$twig->print;

__DATA__
<bookstore>
  <location category="US">
  <book category="cooking">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>XYZ</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
  <book category="sample">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <writer>ABCD</writer>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
 </location>

    <location category="UK">
  <book category="cooking">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
  <book category="sample">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <writer>Giada De Laurentiis</writer>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
 </location>
</bookstore>
```

Which will run through all the books and merge them based on title. So in the example above, you'll get:

```
<bookstore>
  <location category="US">
    <book category="cooking">
      <writer>ABCD</writer>
      <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
      <author>XYZ</author>
      <year>2005</year>
      <price>30.00</price>
    </book>
  </location>
  <location category="UK"></location>
</bookstore>
```

I can't be any more specific without a bit more understanding what you're trying to accomplish, but you can do some quite clever things with an `XML::Twig`.